# Can someone please explain the syntactic rules at work here?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, semantics

I'll use an example statement that's currently being used in a radio commercial for American Family Insurance (paraphrased.)

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; but, I didn't.

Can someone please lex this to identify why `but, I didn't` is referring to the fact that the dream home was built and it was not build `by myself`; whereas `and, I didn't` would introduce ambiguity as to whether the dream home was built or not; or that it was built but not `by myself.`

To state my question another way: if I were to attempt to automate a lexical analysis of this statement -exactly as it has been provided- to conclude that the house was built with the help of others, what rules would I need to consider?

Apart from bare assertions that the sentence parses a different way, can anyone see any alternative interpretations?

### [Edit]

I see the `but` as an adverbial conjunction and that's why my parsing is conflicting with that of others who are seeing it as a coordinating conjunction.

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself, only I didn't.

With this understanding, it is clear to see that this is the structure they are using.  The question now is...is that the proper structure of an adverbial `but`?  It feels natural to me, but by the responses below, others seem to disagree.

Comment: I deny your major: I don't think the *but/and* distinction necessarily implies what you say it does.

Comment: Usually a subsequent sentence would clarify "I built it with the help of a hundred people"... Can you finish the text of the commercial?

Comment: I agree, @StoneyB . Even "so I didn't" wouldn't imply that the house ended up never built... only that he didn't build it alone.

Comment: It sounds a little weird to me. I continue it as "...; but I didn't _build it all alone_." Does that make sense?

Comment: In the phrased sentence, the 'but' usage does imply that the house couldn't be built. I'd like to know why other users think differently here.

Comment: With precisely the right intonation, in precisely the right context (which is likely what was intended in the commercial), this works. **But** you have to stress and intone _didn't_ just right -- and then you have to follow it with the explanation, as pointed out.

Comment: @Andy notice the negation used in the proposition.  The 'but' answers that the house was built, not that it was not.

Comment: Wickipedia  is good on  **syntactical ambiguity**. This amphiboly is an example of a local rather than global ambiguity because the "wrong" meaning is a "garden path" distraction.

Comment: It's a litterary/poetic effect: you always expect the narrator to say "but I did", in that kind of sentence: They say..." or less often "They say such...and they were right" The advertiser gets your attention in mixing the two possible answers to the premisse.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree that the 'and' version of the predicate clause does not stand in stark contradiction of the 'but' version.  I probably shouldn't have mentioned it in my question.  'And' introduces ambiguity as to which piece was not completed (The house actually being built or being done without help)  I do contend that the 'but' states definitively that the house was built leaving only the "by myself" to be the subject of "I didn't"

Comment: I think, though, that it's not a matter of grammar or semantics but of pragmatics. *But* entails some contrast with the preceding clause, but it is left to the hearer/reader to infer where the contrast lies. And as @P.Obertelli says, that's the cunning of the line: it cuts off the ordinary interpretation and compels you to imagine an alternative understanding.

Comment: You could take to mean that he did not tell himself that he couldn't build his dream home by himself.

Comment: @NeilW +1 for seeing that; I didn't (see that )
;)

Comment: Right I agree with @NeilW That's the only logical way in which the given phrase could be construed. :)

Comment: +1, that's a good question! The "but" is a pragmatic thingie that indicates contrast--which I'm sure that you already know. :)

Comment: @AndySemyonov Not sure if your "only logical way" is a riposte to the absolutist language I used to spark discussion.

Comment: @K.AlanBates I can assure you there's no cloaked astringent barb attached to my remark. I merely implied that Neilw's answer was perfectly coherent and made more sense than any I was able to read.

Comment: For the record, I don't like that semicolon.  "But I didn't" is arguably a sentence fragment, and if we assume it's not, then "but" is a coordinating conjunction and we should still be using a comma.

Comment: @Kevin It may be improper, but I expect the semicolon to carry through the excluded event into the context of the conclusion.  There was a statement made in the past. There was a point in time -still in the past- that the truth value of their statement was found or DNC'd.  Then, there is a point in time (either in the present or still in the past but relatively subsequent to the prior statements) where the author is providing their insight to the observer.  I see the semicolon as being more important than the comma.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you didn't mishear the phrase "but I did it?"  it is phonetically extremely similar, would be easy to mishear on the radio, and would make a hell of a lot more sense than this...

Comment: @PaulGriffin In the radio spot, the next statement goes into how his father, who taught him a love of carpentry, "was with him the whole time."  The additional context makes it perfectly clear that the interpretation they are seeking is that he was able to build the dream house because he possessed skills that were taught to him by others.  "They" were with him the whole time he was building the dream house, so he wasn't really alone.  ...(continued)

Comment: ...(continued) I excluded that from my question because I wanted to see if my thoughts that the statement stands on its own at the end of "...but I didn't" was solid or if it necessarily relied on having its context provided by a look-ahead to the statement that followed it.  Certainly, it's intention is not clearly communicated through its structure but neither is it with recursive center-embedded statements. But, they are still syntactically valid and they still have a clear, parsable meaning with a strict examination.

Comment: @Kevin `but` is an adverbial conjunction in the statement, not a coordinating one.

Comment: @K.AlanBates: I've not seen "but" used that way, and it's not on [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb), for whatever that's worth.  I think you're supposed to start with an adverb and use it like a conjunction, not *vice-versa*.

Comment: I'm with Paul Griffin on this. I haven't heard the ad, but I think he might have said "but I did it." That would even fit well with the background of the rest of the ad. Perhaps 200 years ago (or even more recently), if someone said "I will build my house myself", they might have meant it literally... that they would drive every nail, cut every board, by their self. But I don't think that is what was meant here. I see it as he does not want to buy a pre-built home, or some "cookie-cutter" house, he wants to build his own home. (continued)

Comment: (continued)... The work "He" will do to build his home, is to (for example),  buy the land, consult an architect, hire a contractor, perhaps even some hands-on construction work, etc... I don't think he has to "drive every nail and cut every board" to have "built it himself".

Comment: @KevinFegan In the actual radio spot, there is no question that the advertiser who smithed the words crafted the line "but I didn't." It was an evocative structure and the statements that followed went into identifying the people (or their spirits...they didn't specify) that were "with him the whole time."

Comment: @Kevin  There is but one problem with your assessment of `adverbial but`

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a bit of a problem here - the sentence, as provided, without context or a follow-up, is indeed ambiguous.

I'll illustrate first:

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home **by myself**; but, I
> didn't.

This is how you resolved the sentence, with the meaning that the person built the home but had help - **but** this isn't the only way to interpret the sentence!

> They all told me that I couldn't **build** my dream home by myself; but, I
> didn't.

Here the speaker actually didn't build the house at all. What did they do? Well, they could have **grown** the house, as in living in some sort of organic structure. They could have **found** the house of their dreams - perhaps abandoned or lost in some hidden or rarely visited area. They could have also just **bought** the dream home, and this is actually just a clever ad for a real estate agent. Or they could have **inherited** or been **given** it, and perhaps this is an ad for one of those lost-property services or a lawyer/estate planning service.

And actually, this isn't the only way to interpret the sentence either!

> They all told me that **I** couldn't build my dream home by myself; but, **I**
> didn't.

Here the speaker is referring to the fact that they themselves didn't build the dream home at all. This could even be combined with emphasis from the previous interpretation for another similar set of interpretations. Maybe their spouse did it, or their kid, or their grandparent - all are very possible introductions to a potentially interesting story.

---

So, what set of grammatical/syntactic rules are at work? In short: contextual re-interpretation, where ambiguity is resolved with additional information.

The purpose of the sentence is to provide a momentary pause, of confusion, not only because it violates a common template (They said...but I did, or They said...and so I didn't) but also because it is actually ambiguous. No rule leads us to only one interpretation, because it isn't the only valid one. It requires multiple re-readings to get a guess as to what the author might have meant, when no context is available.

Now, you could argue that proximity of "by myself" made the given interpretation **more likely**, and this is indeed a common enough sentence structure that it's a reasonable heuristic. You could also note that the specificity also made this part of the sentence stand out more, as we assume that all detail in a sentence is necessary for the meaning. For instance:

> I told you I didn't want you driving at night; but you did it anyway.

Here we tend to assume that the problem was the "at night", and not the more general "driving" at all, due to both proximity to the objection and due to the specificity. If the speaker objected to driving generally, why did they specify at night? Well, this would also be somewhat ambiguous - because "at night" might have been intended as an intensifier!

Returning to the example sentence, let's look at it again:

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; but, I
> didn't.

Now, why would "by myself" have been included if it wasn't important to the sentence? If they had said instead:

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home; but, I didn't.

This is valid, but takes the natural emphasis away due to proximity and reduces our heuristic certainty. It could still be about going it alone, as they could follow with "my spouse and I built it together". But this seems like the less likely intent now.

However, as with my made-up example sentence, what if "by myself" was intended as an intensifier? The speaker was poor or physically disabled, so "they" said that not only could the speaker not build their own dream home, but they thought it was even more absurd that they'd be able to do it by themselves!

Ultimately, there is no syntactic rule that eliminates ambiguity from this sentence simply because there is still ambiguity. Multiple meaning and intentions are possible, and a reading agent can apply heuristic rules to find more or less statistically likely meanings - but no agent would be able to attain certainty.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for your detailed response and identifying precisely where you feel ambiguity lies. I'm not completely convinced that ambiguity is not resolved by switching the conjunctions. I see "and" "but" and "so" (for example) importing strictly separate contexts for the statement "[insert], I didn't."  (a la Tim Romano's answer)

Comment: Note that I didn't think about the answer to this question much before posting it. I thought it would be more interesting to discuss rather than sit and mull over.  I contend that the structure of the conclusion with both "but" and "didn't" are relating directly to the truth value of the external statement made by "all."  The switch of usage across the semicolon from "couldn't" to "didn't" imparts a specific meaning. The "but" states that "all" were wrong. The "didn't" applies to the "couldn't" and implies that the deed (building the dream home) was in fact, completed.

Comment: I contend that the usage of "by myself" as an intensifier here would require a conjunctive adverb such as `especially not`

Comment: You seem to be missing the most obvious interpretation:  that the speaker never obtained his dream house at all.

Answer (score 1):

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; but, (the thing is,) I didn't (try to do it, I had help).

He's saying they were wrong to assume I was trying to build it by myself.

EDIT:

The conjunction `AND`, unlike `BUT`, doesn't always provide contrast. Therefore, you might be right in saying that using `and` is ambiguous here. It could mean:

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; and (they were right), I didn't.

But I think that even here, the interpretation that the house wasn't built at all is far-fetched. If the speaker wanted to say that, they'd be more likely to say:

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; and (they were right), I **couldn't**.

Comment: I'm aware of what he was saying. I'm asking someone to produce an explanation of why the `but` leaves only "by myself" to be the subject of "I didn't" whereas `and` leaves an ambiguity.  I can see that this is what "but" and "and" are doing in this statement, but I cannot formally state why it is that they are operating in this manner under this structure.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and I think that if @K.AlanBates wants to state the correct answer formally but can't, he needs to extend his formalism until he can.  If a formal grammatical theory is not sufficient to describe correct analyses, then what good is it?

Comment: @GregLee that is a very puzzling non-answer.  If I'm saying "Hey, can someone please formally explain this because I can see the beginning and I can see the end but I'm fuzzy on how it gets there" how is your comment anything but non sequitur?  In fact, as far as your comment is concerned, the site should just be shut down.  Every question can be answered with "go figure that out for yourself."

Comment: @K.AlanBates, I agree that it's not much of an answer.  A good answer would be to give a formal theory of conversation which incorporates the informal ideas of this answer.  I'll have to get back to you on that.  It's a bit of a project.

Comment: Identifying that my interpretation was predicated on the understanding that the `but` was an adverbial conjunction would have sufficed.  That's the "middle" that I wasn't quite getting (and it is clearly the structure they were using in the statement)  The question now is `is that structure syntactically valid for an adverbial but`? If you perform the `but->only` substitution for an adverbial but, the statement reads clearly.  But I'm not quite sure that there isn't something missing from the statement because modifying the `I` that follows doesn't seem quite proper to my ear.

Comment: What I'm saying is that my reading was exactly as they were trying to communicate. I read the `but` as `only` and `only I didn't` reads nicely.  What I'm not quite certain of is whether the rule for being able to directly replace `but` with `only` actually applies given the structure they used. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; but, I
>   didn't.
>
> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; but, I
>   didn't *build my dream home by myself*.

They were wrongheaded to warn (or predict) that I would be unable to build the dream house on my own because it was never my intention to act alone.

The "but" denies "their" premise, the very basis for their warning or prediction. It does not deny the truth-content of the warning or prediction itself.

P.S. Consider:

> They all warned me that I wouldn't make it to the wedding on time if I
>   took the tunnel, *so* I didn't.
>
> They all warned me that I wouldn't make it to the wedding on time if I
>   took the tunnel; *but*, I didn't.

"So" makes perfectly logical sense. He did not take the tunnel because he had been warned of the traffic.

"But" does not make logical sense unless we understand "I didn't" to mean "I did not take the tunnel and *never intended* to take the tunnel." The "but" means "they had no need to *warn* me".  It does not deny that the tunnel would have been a bad idea.  It is the dramatic context of the conversation which is the referent of "but", not heavy traffic in the tunnel.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a touch more nuanced than my initial interpretation, but I see us more in agreement than disagreement. (and I think I see the A Ha! that I was looking for) You are focusing the `but` on "they all warned;" however, I am seeing the meaning of "but, I didn't" to mean the same with or without "They all warned me that" ...I'll edit my initial question to add detail.

Comment: I just figured out how it is that we are right.  The `but` is used as an adverbial conjunction.  The meaning of the statement is identical to the rephrasing:  `They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; only, I didn't.`

Comment: @K. Alan Bates: succinct.

Comment: Much virtue in *only*.

Answer (score 0):

There is little difference between these two ellipses:

> They all told me that I couldn't ( build my dream home by myself;) but
> I didn't (build my dream home by myself.)
>
> They all told me that I couldn't ( build my dream home by myself;) and
> I didn't (build my dream home by myself.)

It is a matter of **Rhetoric**: Possibly ***Suggestio falsi*** [1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suggestio_falsi) (Wikipedia), that you hear it as

> They all told me that I couldn't (build my dream home by myself;) but
> I didn't.

Or **Psycholinguistics**: Compare Wikipedia - **Garden_path_sentence**

> A garden path sentence is a grammatically correct sentence that starts
> in such a way that a reader's most likely interpretation will be
> incorrect; the reader is lured into a parse that turns out to be a
> dead end. Garden path sentences are used in psycholinguistics to
> illustrate the fact that when human beings read, they process language
> one word at a time. "Garden path" refers to the saying "to be led down
> the garden path", meaning "to be misled".[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)

Answer (score 0):

I see this as holding a very strict context with one and only one possible valid interpretation.

A statement was made by "all" at some point in the past that has a truth value.

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself

If I merely believe that I could build a dream home by myself, I would have a weak disagreement with their assertion because both would be hypothetical. If I *built* a dream home by myself, I would have a strong conclusion to negate their assertion. If I attempted and failed to build a dream home by myself, I would have a strong conclusion to affirm their assertion.

I contend that the addition of "by myself" is not merely an intensifier that tries to add that "I can't build my dream home [even with help] and I especially can't build it by myself." That statement would be

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home, especially not by myself

An intensifier of this structure requires a conjunctive adverb.
Without the conjunctive adverb, `by myself` is the major component of the premise.

Carrying through the semicolon, the context of `all`'s statement is imported for the concluding one.  To move past the conjunction for a moment, the `didn't` decorates that conjunction and applies to the `couldn't` from the premise made by `all.` Usage of a word that does not directly coincide with `all`'s usage of `couldn't` necessarily imparts a tone of deflection.  Usage of `didn't` denies that `all`'s premise was ever under consideration.

To discuss alternatives first to address other potential, invalid, interpretations:

If assessment of the statement made by `all` was being evaluated by `myself` for consideration when building a dream home, the word could or couldn't would instead be used.

> ;and, I couldn't

would be used to state "they were right" but place the statement of the conclusion in an ambiguous temporal setting. 
It could potentially mean that the assessment made by `all` was agreed with, and no attempt `to build a dream home by myself` has been made.
It could potentially mean that the assessment made by `all` was disagreed with, but a failed attempt `to build a dream home by myself` was made.

At any rate, `and I couldn't` would be used for these, not the structure as provided.

> but, I could

would be used to state that I reject their notion that I could build it by myself but carry no truth value of whether the dream home was built.  It would be perfectly valid to interpret this as `but, I (know I) could` to indicate subjective disagreement with `all` but no objective truth to the statement.

> but, I couldn't

makes no logical sense within the context I am currently discussing.  It only applies to a very novel interpretation of the statement that `They all told me, but I couldn't tell myself.`

> and, I could

exists in the same vein as `but, I couldn't` It means `They all told me, and I could tell myself` although this is fairly weak.

> and, I couldn't

is perfectly consistent with the assessment made by `all.` It very clearly means that I either tried to build my dream home by myself and failed or I agreed with their assessment and did not try to build my dream home by myself.

---

Usage of `did` implies something very different.

> but, I did

means something very clear. They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself. But I did, in fact, build it by myself.

> and, I did

is weird. I'm not certain that it is even valid given the logical structure. I see it only working with a very specific addition, consistent with the novel approach.  `They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home` and, I [told myself that as well].

> and, I didn't

is slightly ambiguous but has one strong and one weak meaning. The strong meaning is that they told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself. I tried to build my dream home by myself and I failed.  The weak meaning is that they told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself and I did not tell that to myself.

> but, I didn't

The `but` is used here as an adverbial conjunction.  That's why the `and` versions of the statements seem clumsy and why `but, I did` seems very clear. The perceived discomfort with this version likely comes from the way the sentence was ended with an unfamiliar sounding phrase and the way the structure makes it sound somewhat as if the `but` is used as a simple conjunction.

> They all told me that I couldn't build my dream home by myself; only I didn't.

Comment: ...cannot believe this categorized breakdown never got any love lol